# Spring JPQL Processing Dates

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot/Framework/JPA to read a PostgreSQL database table. However, I have a situation where I want to SELECT from a column that is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` / `OffsetDateTime`, but I only want to compare on the date, not the time.

I have tried the following (in Kotlin), based on things I have found after Googling, but both of these are giving me syntax errors, saying that it does not expect the left paren. Without the functions, it matches on date and time.

```
    @Query(
        """select odi from on_deck_inventory odi
        where odi.sku = :sku
        and odi.storeId = :storeId
        and date(odi.transactionDate) = :transactionDate
        and odi.restocked = :restocked
        """
    )
```

```
    @Query(
        """select odi from on_deck_inventory odi
        where odi.sku = :sku
        and odi.storeId = :storeId
        and date = cast(:transactionDate as date)
        and odi.restocked = :restocked
        """
    )
```

It appears that JPQL does not allow any kind of functions in the query. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using JPQL, which is fairly limited, and doesn't recognize those functions. However, when I used the native SQL query, it works.

```
    @Query(
        """select * from on_deck_inventory odi
        where odi.sku = :sku
        and odi.store_id = :storeId
        and date(odi.transaction_date) = :transactionDate
        and odi.restocked = :restocked
        """,
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    fun findBySkuAndStoreIdAndTransactionDateAndRestocked(
        @Param("sku") sku: String,
        @Param("storeId") storeId: Int,
        @Param("transactionDate") transactionDate: LocalDate,
        @Param("restocked") restocked: Boolean = false
    ): OnDeckInventoryEntity?
```